# how to send web request to check the link whether the link is broken or not

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

i am having text box(multi line) from that i want to send the web request to all links to check whether the link is working or not if not working then message of error

```
string strLink = TextBox1.Text;
WebResponse objResponse;
WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strLink);

objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    strLink = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
strLink = strLink.Replace("<form id='form1' method='post' action=''>", "");
strLink = strLink.Replace("</form>", "");
//strResult = strResult.Replace("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" /><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">");
div.InnerHtml = TextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: why are you doing `strLink = sr.ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: to end readding of string

Comment: but `strLink` will contain a big text with all the links. First of all, you're not parsing each link from that text. And what I meant with my last comment, is that you are assigning the HTML text that your 1st url returned (supposing you called it correctly) to that same variable, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: Did you create another user and asked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105994/how-to-get-webresponce-in-new-textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you, you can do something like this:

```
var links = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var link in links) {
    if (!IsLinkWorking(link)) {
        //Here you can show the error. You don't specify how you want to show it.
        textBox2.Text += string.Format("Link {0} not working\n", link);
    }
}

bool IsLinkWorking(string url) {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    //You can set some parameters in the "request" object...
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

    try {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        return true;
    } catch { //TODO: Check for the right exception here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Assuming you had in `textBox1` something like this:

> http://www.stackoverflow.com/
>   http://www.invalid-page.com/
>   http://www.invalid.again.com/120938213

You will end up with the following text in `textBox2`:

> Link http://www.invalid-page.com/ not working
>   Link http://www.invalid.again.com/120938213 not working

Comment: thanks i am implementing this code

Comment: sorry bro not working as i want ,i want that i have list of links in textbox1 and from that i want send webrequest to each one then check if the link is broken or not if broken then send particular error message and that all will have to show in textbox2

Comment: If you have one link per line in `textBox1`, the 1st line of my question give you all the links in `links`. Then, for each link, you check if it is valid or not. If not valid, you can do what you want. Please, try to be more specific (perhaps showing an example of `textBox1`, what exact error do you want to show, etc.)

Comment: @hitarth I edited my answer. Please, edit your question to include more details.

Comment: you know the site link checker exactly i want working like that,

Comment: @hitarth what part of my answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: your code working but as per not my requirement ,its simple i want to send the webrequest to all links  and then it will check the link one by one and then it will show the link in textbox2 with the status of all links if its working then it will say message "working" below the link but in textbox2

Comment: yes like this only bro....nice

Comment: I'm sorry if it is not working as per your requirements. We don't usually do your project/homework/whatever for you. There you have a way of doing something similar (with an example). Try to adapt it to your requirements.

Comment: bro its working but just suggest me  how to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpWebResponse status as bellow:

```
HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
if (objResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   // put your code when link is valid.
}
```

You can also put the code inside the `try catch` to catch some exception e.g connection failure, etc.

Comment: That won't work. If the site returns an `(404) Not Found` error, it will fail on the 1st line.

Comment: yu can put it inside try catch to handle an exception.

Comment: sorry bro not working as i want ,i want that i have list of links in textbox1 and from that i want send webrequest to each one then check if the link is broken or not if broken then send particular error message and that all will have to show in textbox2